# Can a ViewComponent have it's own seperate js file?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

In the same way a normal cshtml file can have a js file section, doe same apply for a ViewComponent?  If so are there any gotchas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewComponents have their own `cshtml` files, which render out to plain HTML, so you can just include the javascript as you would in HTML, within the `cshtml` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('rendered viewcomponent');
</script>
```